# Security options keeping us from testing applications

Tags: facebook, security, sms, account

I work for a iPhone game developer. We use Facebook as a way for people to register their account to easily add friends and post news of their game progress.

We have created several Facebook accounts to test game account attachment and various friend features our game has.

Unfortunately, recently added security features are preventing us from logging into our test accounts. We are being asked to enter in a cellphone number to receive a SMS with a code to enter so we can verify they are real people. Unfortunately, after a phone number is used once, it cannot be used for any other account. So at the moment, we have two accounts that can be used, and about a dozen accounts that are inaccessible to us.

I haven't been able to find any solutions to this problem and we are really short on time at the moment so I need one ASAP.

Comment: Have you contacted Facebook directly?

Comment: Get in contact with FB's developer relations.  [Doug Purdy](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/417/) might be a good person to ask.  He probably has a FB page.

Answer (score 4):

They dont want you to create accounts like that, they want you to create accounts like [this](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/test_users/)

Comment: Unfortunately that seems to only work for web testing. I passed it along to our programmers and they are telling me it wont work on the iPhone.

Comment: [iOS Facebook SDK Test Account Creation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7700338/how-do-you-create-a-facebook-test-user-in-ios-using-the-facebook-sdk) another answered StackOverflow question.

Answer (score 0):

This is odd, when I have test user accounts they never ask me to confirm the account.  Maybe you should generate new test users for your app at: https://developers.facebook.com/apps/{yourAppId}/permissions.  Then click on Add in the test user section.